# Is the preposition in or on used after the noun ''effects''

Tags: prepositions, nouns

I'm doubting which preposition — on or in — is better to use after the plural noun "effects". For example in the following sentence:

> The biggest announcement effects **on** the [some] bond market are found for those announcements that [explination]

*or*

> The biggest announcement effects **in** the [some] bond market are found for those announcements that [explanation]

And so there are many more of these examples where I doubt if either *on* or *in* is right.

Comment: Basically the choice of preposition depends on the context, but "in" is used more often with living things, although in that case "on" is also appropriate. For example:
The effect of diet in/on children.

Comment: To check preposition selection, look it up in a good dictionary.
According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, effect selects the preposition on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did look it up in the dictionary. However, in the economic literature both prepositions are used, but I do not know why and what would be the right choice in this example.

Comment: If you want to choose the correct option then I'd like to select 'on'. Because I have often seen it on different places.

Comment: Hello, it can help you : http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-in-and-on/

Comment: Just check this too :http://www.dailywritingtips.com/when-to-use-on-and-when-to-use-in/

Comment: Very useful! Thanx a lot!

Comment: This may seem off-topic, but could you elucidate what original idea behind the example sentences is, for hard as I try to get it, it keeps evading me?

Comment: Sure: I am writing my master thesis about the effects of unconventional monetary policy announcements by the Fed on the eurozone government bond markets. Before I assess that relationship, I first examine how these announcements affected the US government bond market. That is where the sentences are about.

Comment: "the greatest effects of the announcement **on the bond market"** but your sentence is not super good.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is "in".

[Market history: Jonathan's Coffee House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Stock_Exchange#Coffee_House)

Public auctions have been held for hundreds of years, allowing merchants to buy commodities at a future point in time (futures or forwards). The markets have grown and become largely electronic, however in certain exchanges like Frankfurt and the NYSE, you can still trade on the floor (in the pit).

Financial markets today are still markets despite the fact that most of the trades are conducted remotely.

**Definition of market**

1. A regular gathering of people for the purchase and sale of provisions, livestock, and other commodities.
2. An area or arena in which commercial dealings are conducted.

Therefore you buy or sell **in** a financial market, in the same way you would buy or sell **in** a flea market.

**The rise of "on the market"**

The use of **on** the market has increased for a few reasons.

Firstly, because "bond market" has become so over complicated that it is seen to be a black box. You would act **on** a box.

Secondly, because "stock" markets show listings, the original stock markets were chalk boards matching buyers and sellers, so technically you could chalk up your sale **on** the board or **on** the stock exchange listing.  However, unless you are referring explicitly to listing a trade **on** a chalkboard (which they still do in some emerging markets), then again, you are referring to activity **in** the market.

NOTE: This contradicts a similar answer in the "english language" forum which suggests that the bond market is an abstraction.  However, after many years working in the investment banking sector, I can assure you that there is nothing abstract about the bond market.  The market works on fundamentally the same principles as conception many centuries ago, but with larger volumes, faster transactions and on computers instead of chalkboards.

So this is not about the use of the prepositions on/in, this is about the definition of "bond market", which is not some esoteric object but which is (or should be) a simple exchange of products.

Comment: effects **on a market**, The effects on the bond market were devastating,for example. effects on any market, in fact. The best preposition is on, not in.

Answer (score 1):

Both "on" and "in" can be used here.  The correct answer depends on exactly what you want to say:

> effects **on** the bond market

This is referring to the effect that something will have on the market as a whole (that is, whether the total value/etc will go up or down across all of the bonds in the market).

> effects **in** the bond market

This is referring to the effects that something will have on individual bonds within the market, at a more detailed level.

It is also not that uncommon for people to sometimes say "on" when they actually mean to talk about individual stocks/bonds/etc, instead of the market as a whole.  This is technically not correct, but common enough that it's not really considered wrong by most people.